# GeoPandas .set_geometry() does not update Geometry of GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, shapefile, geometry, geopandas, geodataframe

I'm trying to implement a transformation of x and y coordinates for line features of a Shapefile. `geopandas.set_geometry()` isn't setting the x and y coordinates and isn't giving me any errors.

Here is my code:

```py
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd

def calcNewXY(geom):
    return geom.geometry.map(
        lambda line: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y: (x - 100000, y - 10000), line)
    )

data = gpd.read_file(inFile)
data.set_geometry(calcNewXY(data))
```

The actual coordinate transformation works, I debugged this part.
Maybe somebody can shed some light on what I'm missing here.

***SOLUTION:***

`inplace=True` has to be set as suggested by @mikewatt

```py
data.set_geometry(calcNewXY(data), inplace=True)
```

Comment: just an error because i simplified the x and y calculation. this part acutally works. i checked that.

Comment: How are you checking the result?  In code, or in some other GIS software?  Do you just need to save the file?

Comment: taking a look at the data with the debugger, writing a shapefile or dxf are the ways i checked the result. the transformation makes quite a big change to x and y so the difference is obvious.

Comment: Can you provide some data sample for reproducibility?

Comment: `shapely.ops.transform` takes two args, `func` and `geom`.  You're only feeding in `func` as written, it should be throwing a syntax error.  If I were you I'd re-write this using named functions to make it easier to debug, nested lambdas is a lil messy

Comment: it doesn't throw an error. the actual x and y transformation works.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  If it works for you then we're not looking at the same code.

Comment: now it does work. someone edited the function and delete a ) to much ...

Comment: Got it.  Works now.  Looks like you need `data.set_geometry(calcNewXY(data), inplace=True)` to avoid creating a new object: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_geometry.html

Comment: Please put your edit as a valid answer!

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is to overwrite the `data` i.e.

```py
data = data.set_geometry(calcNewXY(data))
```

See [GeoPandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_geometry.html#geopandas-geodataframe-set-geometry) for more details.

Comment: This is preferable to operating in-place and it opens the possibility to chain additional operations